# IE: Conditional commenting linking to file

Tags: html

all. I'm using conditional commenting in IE to fix some CSS problem that i'm having with IE7.

I have a all.css file that work on firefox and ie7 with some execptions that will only fix the IE7 css problem. I put my fix on all_iefixes.css both files is in App_Themes/Default/ folder.

I use have a master page (Default.master) that all my pages inherited. On some page that is inside another folder, for example, localhost/myapp/blah1/blah.aspx will not get the all_iefixes.css in the App_Themes/Default folder If i change the

```
<!--[if IE]><style type="text/css">@import "all_iefixes.css";</style><![endif]-->
```

to

```
<!--[if IE]><style type="text/css">@import "./../App_Themes/Default/all_iefixes.css";</style><![endif]-->
```

then it will work for the page inside the blah1 folder but it will break other page that doesn't live inside blah1 folder.

I think i can create several master page and depend on where i want to put my aspx pages to live then i can adjust the link but i think this is a rather "stupid" fix (?). Is there an elegant way to do this.

Jack

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid using relative paths in your master pages unless you can generate it with code:

You can try using server tags to resolve the path, but this is not always possible (for instance, if youre manipulating the control tree in code)

```
@import "<% this.ResolveUrl("~/App_Themes/Default/all_iefixes.css") %>";
```

Comment: Yes, within the conditional comment, OR print the entire conditional comment with the ResolveUrl method call entirely from code.

Answer (score 0):

+1 from the ablove. However, I'd rather use [browser files in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228122.aspx).

Comment: Hello, do you have a tutorial link regarding on how to use browser file to determine which CSS file to load?